# Put additional logic in server.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've the server.js file which is the starting point of my node application and also responsible to invoke 3 different functions( this functions are invoked just once when the server is up , function like create childProcess ,validaton etc ) which is OK.

**My questions is**

1. Should I put this logic (3 functions below) in different file in the
   controller folder or its OK to keep it on the server.js file(SOC?)?
2. If I put those functions calls in different file (in the controller
   folder) should I invoke those functions via **event**(like event
   serverIsUp...) Example for this approach will be very helpful

The server.js look like following(in short...)

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    }
});

...
//Here it the function which is called when the server is up and running 
childProcess.createProcess() ;

fileParser.parse();

invokeValidations();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new file (or several ones for each function) and export/require the function:

In `newfile.js` you export the function

```
exports.invokeValidations = function () {
    // Do something
}
```

In `server.js` you require the file and invoke the function

```
myFunctions = require('./newfile.js');

myFunctions.invokeValidations();
```

And for you should or not, that's up to you, if functions increase I would recommend to put them into separate files to keep stuff organised.

**EDIT:**

To use event emitter you should create your own emitter:

`emitter.js`:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var localEmitter = new EventEmitter();

module.exports = localEmitter;
```

Then you should require it in server.js and in your module.js

`server.js`:

```
var myEmitter = require('./emitter');
    myModule = require('./module');

myEmitter.on('boot', function(){
    console.log('hello world !');
});


myModule.invokeValidations();
```

`module.js`:

```
var myEmitter = require('./emitter');

exports.invokeValidations = function () {
   myEmitter.emit('boot');
   // Do something
};
```

And you are done

Comment: Thanks 1+ Do you think that this is better then invoke it as event ? assume that I wan to invoke it as event from different module can you please provide example ?

Comment: As you wrote your code the 3 functions are invoked immediately after run the node file. If you need to run them after the http server is up, you just need to put them into the `else` statement. If you need to run them after specific events, you could use event too.

Comment: Ok Thanks ,can you please provide example if I want to invoke specific function in from diff module how should I do that ? like the fileParser function to invoke via event.Thank sir!

Comment: I added an example but I don't know you are doing, so please keep it only as sample and write a new question if you have specific one.